# Cauchy-Riemann on holomorphic sets

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

I am given $e^{z^2+3z+4}$ and asked to state the subsets of $\mathbb C$ on which the following function is holomorphic, and to calculate the derivative on its domains of holomorphicity. My first step is to put this in Cauchy-Riemann form.

so I let $z=x+iy$

which gives me $^{(x+iy)^2+3(x+iy)+4}$

when simplified I get $^{x^2+2xyi-y^2+3x+3iy+4}$

this simplifies to $^{x^2-y^2+3x+4}e^{2xyi+3iy}$

which simplifies to $^{x^2-y^2+3x+4}(\cos(2xy+3y)+i\sin(2xy+3y))$

and if I distribute then $e^{x^2-y^2+3x+4}(\cos(2xy+3y)+e^{x^2-y^2+3x+4}i\sin(2xy+3y)$

I don't know where to go from this point, help would be appreciated

Comment: There’s no need for Cauchy-Riemann, that just obfuscates things. Composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic. The exponential $\exp$ is holomorphic, and so is every polynomial. So…

Comment: @peek-a-boo noted, but I would like to solve this particular problem using Cauchy-riemann

Comment: ok well, that’s going to be more tedious. In the end you should find that CR holds at every point of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: I saw the same question yesterday and I already commented that this function is an entire function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of proving that this particular function is holomorphic everywhere, it would be more advantageous to prove (rigorously) that compositions of holomorphic functions are holomorphic, and then to prove that $e^z$ and complex polynomials are holomorphic, at which point your question is just a particular example of a composition of exponential and polynomial function.

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$: If $f(z)$ is holomorphic in domain $D$ then so is $e^{f(z)}$. 
Can you see that why $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane $\mathbb C$?